# how to get value before and behind decimal point in string

Tags: php

My PHP file receives (via $_POST) strings (with constant prefix) like:

(constant prefix in this example = 'astring'; figure before and after the decimal point can vary in size)

- astring1.1
- astring1.2
  ..
- astring23.2
- astring23.6

How to get the value behind the decimal point? I know how to extract the total figure from the constant prefix, but I need to use the figures before and after the decimal point and don't know how to extract those. Using preg_match in some way?

Comment: Do u need only the number or full astring1

Comment: spliting string you can php explode() function, For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @Altaf: I need the numbers before and after the decimal point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `explode` like

```
$str = 'astring23.2'; 
$str_arr = explode('.',$str);
echo $str_arr[0];  // Before the Decimal point
echo $str_arr[1];  // After the Decimal point
```

Comment: thnx, this works for; other solutions like from Benno also work (however, I need both figures before and after the decimal point)

Answer (score 5):

If you want the number before the decimal. Try This.

```
$number = 2.33;
echo floor($number);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list($before, $after) = explode(".", $string);

echo "$before is the value before the decimal point!";
echo "$after is the value after the decimal point!";
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way (php 5.3+):

```
$str = 'astring23.2';
$pre = strstr($str, '.', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something similar?

```
    <?php
        $string = "astring23.6";
        $data = explode("astring", $string);    // removed prefix string "astring" and get the decimal value            
        list($BeforeDot, $afterDot)=explode(".", $data[1]); //split the decimal value   
        echo "BeforeDot:".$BeforeDot." afterDot: ".  $afterDot;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only numbers, use like this

```
$str = 'astring23.2'; 
$str_arr = explode('.',$str);
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]/i","",$str_arr[0]);  // Before the Decimal point
echo $str_arr[1]; // After decimal point
```